# Window switching error in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, automation, browser-automation

I have one requirement where I need to perform some dropdown action(selecting a value from dropdown list) in a child window which gets redirected from a parent window in a for loop. That is there are multiple rows within the parent window & I need to iterate through all the rows, click the hyperlink & select the same value from the dropdown list. But I am constantly facing error while window switching only.

One thing to mention that the child window opens on the same place, that is the child window is not a popup window and the elements in both the window is under iFrame having same name & id.

I have stored all the incident values which I need to iterate in the list `incident_list`.

I have the below code snippet

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'M:\Parvej\Softwares\Python-Selenium\geckodriver.exe')
browser.get('<URL ADDRESS>')
emailElem = browser.find_element_by_id('i0116')
emailElem.send_keys('user@gmail.com')
linkElem = browser.find_element_by_id('idSIButton9')
linkElem.click()
time.sleep(10);

list = browser.find_element_by_tag_name('iframe')

iframe1 = browser.find_element_by_id("gsft_main")

browser.switch_to.frame(iframe1)
time.sleep(10)

incident_list = []
for tr_incidents in browser.find_elements_by_partial_link_text('INC'):
    incidents = tr_incidents.text
    incident_list.append(incidents)

print(incident_list)

for inc in incident_list:
    str1=browser.title
    print(str1)
    #get the window handles using window_handles( ) method
    window_before = browser.window_handles[0]
    print(window_before)

    #since the pop-up is now in an iframe
    #DID NOT SWITCH TO IFRAME BCOZ I HAVE ALREADY SWITCHED TO IT ABOVE
    #browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element_by_id('gsft_main'))
    inc_elem = browser.find_element_by_link_text(inc)
    inc_elem.click()

    #get the window handle after a new window has opened
    window_after = browser.window_handles[1]

    #switch on to new child window
    browser.switch_to.window(window_after)

    str2=browser.title
    print(str2)
    print(window_after)

    #assert that main window and child window title don't match
    self.assertNotEqual(str1,str2)
    print('This window has a different title')

    #switch back to original window
    browser.switch_to.window(window_before)

    #assert that the title now match
    self.assertEqual(str1,browser.title)

    print('Returned to parent window. Title now match')
    #browser.back()
```

But while doing this each time I am getting the error :

`window_after = browser.window_handles[1]
IndexError: list index out of range`

Please help me to resolve this.

Thanks & Regards,